# VScode output displays paths, then code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

New to VScode and while I like it, I feel I may have either set something up wrong or its just slower than Atom or sublime3. When running simple code it takes around 5 seconds for this simple "Hello World" to display.

Why does it display all the path nonsense and is that why it sees so slow? Any ways to tune this?

Thanks!

Visual studio Output:

```
user_dev@DESKTOP-131452 MINGW64 ~/Documents/VSCODE/Python/BeautifulSoup
$ cd "C:\Users\user_dev\Documents\VSCODE\Python\BeautifulSoup" ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" C:/Python3/python.exe "C:\Users\user_dev\.
vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.3.1\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_launcher_nodebug.py" "C:\Users\user_dev\Documents\VSCODE\Python\BeautifulSou
p" 55240 34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14 RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput "c:\Users\user_dev\Documents\VSCODE\Python\BeautifulSoup\Training\example.py"
Hello World
```

Tried the same thing in Atom and its blazing fast, ATOM output:

```
Hello World
[Finished in 0.662s]
```

**Update:**

Code run above to get output:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

Python version:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.4
```

Comment: Anyone else have this issue or know the fix?

Comment: i run python often in Atom but it runs quickly and does not give me all the info you show, just results.

Comment: What version of python are you running, how do you execute the python code, and what is first few lines of your python code?

Comment: The above comments pertain to VScode, not Atom...

Comment: @jmh Ive updated the post above, I hit CTRL + F5 to run the code. I feel this can be fixed maybe by the visual studio settings but not sure where...